# Running SAS programs from excel

Tags: excel, vba, sas

I have a few SAS programs that I need to run from excel. The programs pull tables from SQL, perfom some calculations and give an output table that I would like to present in Excel. So I figured that it would be great to run everything in excel.

There are a few parameters in the code that need to be changed before running, so the best idea I had is to put the SAS scripts in cells on an excel sheet and change the variables with VBA.

My question is, is this achievable? Can I connect to SAS and do everything from excel?

I'm fairly good with VBA, starting to learn SAS, but I don't really know how to connect the two. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Any chance you have a license for SAS Add in for Excel? If you do, this is very simple.  I'm assuming you have a SAS script already that generates what you need to a neat Excel file using ODS? Or just an EXPORT? ODS is a lot more powerful because of the formatting options so not sure how it aligns with Excel.

Comment: I do have SAS integration Technologies installed, but unfortunately no add in for Excel. Yes, the scripts are reafy to run!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible , i did this in my work a week ago , SAS have an documentation here?

The link below can help you.

http://documentation.sas.com/api/docsets/itechwcdg/9.4/content/itechwcdg.pdf?locale=en

You can use ADODB to connect to , see here for the strings

https://www.connectionstrings.com/sas/

Answer (score -1):

Your options are:

1) use VBA to connect to IOM, create a workspace, run your program.

This requires quite a bit of VBA, as well as the SAS Addin for MSO, and various components.

2) Run a Stored Process (STP) via point and click using the MSO addin

Again, this requires a desktop SAS Addin deployment, and isn't scriptable with VBA

3) Run a Stored Process as a web query

This is an excellent option - you don't need any special desktop installation, you can easily add (url) parameters, you can use it with / without VBA, and your output will render easily into your worksheet so long as you stream tab delimited data via the _webout fileref (without `%stpxxx` macros).  It will also work with all versions of excel and SAS.

This approach is described here:  https://www.rawsas.com/sas-as-a-service-an-easy-way-to-get-sas-into-excel-power-bi-and-000s-of-other-tools-languages/